# Taxonomy terms from multiple vocabs on a single line

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, entities

I migrated from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and used the same theme, now the "post tags" (taxonomy terms from multiple vocabularies) aren't displayed on the same line as shown below.

[image: Taxonomy Terms on multiple lines]

How to get these into a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change in my `style.css` did the trick :

```
.node .taxonomy,
.node .field-type-taxonomy-term-reference {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: inline;
  /* padding-left: 1.5em; */
}
```